# List all Azure Data factories in the subscription using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to list all Azure Datafactories in a subscription using below code. I know the "list" from factories operation class is not properly defined but I am not getting much info about its usage sample from documentation, if any one please advise. #newtopython

```
     from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
     from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
     from DataFactoryManagement import list
     from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
     from datetime import datetime, timedelta
     import time
     credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
         client_id='#####################',
         secret='###########',
         tenant='#############################'
     )
     subscription_id = '################'
     client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
     adf = client.factories:list()
     print (adf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list all the ADFs in the subscription, you need to use the [`list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.operations.factoriesoperations?view=azure-python#list-custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method, it works fine on my side.

*Sample:*

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient

subscription_id = 'xxxxx'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='xxxxx', secret='xxxxx', tenant='xxxxx')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

Factories = adf_client.factories.list()
for factory in Factories:
    print(factory)
```

[image]